# How does one tell if a LINQ extension method is suffering from double enumeration?

Tags: c#, .net, linq

I am wondering what rules there are to tell if a portion of LINQ code is suffering from double enumeration?

For example, what are the telltale signs that the following code might be double enumerating? What are some other signs to look out for?

```
public static bool MyIsIncreasingMonotonicallyBy<T, TResult>(this IEnumerable<T> list, Func<T, TResult> selector)
    where TResult : IComparable<TResult>
{
    return list.Zip(list.Skip(1), (a, b) => selector(a).CompareTo(selector(b)) <= 0).All(b     => b);
}
```

Comment: Probably the fact that you access `list` and apply a LINQ method to it more than once.  Also, ReSharper has a nice inspection that alerts you to this.

Comment: In this case, you're clearly referring to `list` twice, and both of your uses of `list` end up forcing it to be enumerated. But I am not at all confident this is a good explanation.

Comment: If you are asking if there is any general behaviors that would be associated with "Double Enumeration" I can tell you that there is none. Since IEnumerable is an interface, and any behavior would be highly dependent on implementation of the IEnumerable.

Answer (score 7):

Pass in one of these:

```
public class OneTimeEnumerable<T> : IEnumerable<T>
{
  public OneTimeEnumerable(IEnumerable<T> source)
  {
    _source = source; 
  }

  private IEnumerable<T> _source;
  private bool _wasEnumerated = false;

  public IEnumerator<T> GetEnumerator()
  {
    if (_wasEnumerated)
    {
      throw new Exception("double enumeration occurred");
    }
    _wasEnumerated = true;
    return _source.GetEnumerator();
  }

}
```